# Error when loading new activity from fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, listadapter

I have an error that I just can't work out. I've been at it for hours and everywhere I look just gives me the same response.

So here is the method where I call the activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_add:
            actionBar.hide();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Let's add a dream", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            fragment = new addDreamFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            break;

        case R.id.action_view:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Let's see those dreams...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DreamListActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        case R.id.action_share:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item 2 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    actionBar.show();
    return true;
}
```

It's calling from a FragmentActivity to a ListActivity.

This is the error I continue to receive:

```
06-23 09:02:54.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2035): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{swin.examples.cloud/swin.examples.cloud.DreamListActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

I have three xml files, one for main, one for the listactivity and another for generating the list adapter. Could someone please help me out? Also, I'd like to start the listactivity from inside a fragment as well, some help in making that work would be appreciated as well!

XML FILE ONE: Main layout for fragment activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/container" />
```

XML FILE TWO: Layout for ListActivity:
    The editors being weird and not showing it. It's just a FrameLayout declaration.

XML FILE THREE: LIST VIEW

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5sp"
    android:textSize="25sp" >

<!--Creates the row for the ListAdapter in the ListActivity. -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_dreams" />

</TextView>
```

Comment: as in log :`Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'` means you will need to add listview id in xml as `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: Which xml? I have it in the listrow xml that generates the android:id/list, should it be in my main layout for the listactivity?

Comment: in xml file in which u have added ListView

Comment: try this in your xml `<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" `

Comment: XML files added. Join me in being confused!

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I needed to rearrange the objects in the xml files. It is all fixed now. Thank you for your help.